# HttpClient.GetStringAsync() call freezes everything without throwing an error, but only under specific conditions

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, async-await, win-universal-app

I'm writing a Windows Universal app that relies heavily on information from a REST service.  To facilitate this (and provide caching support), I'm writing an accompanying library that the app will call into.  At the core of the code is the following function:

**PokeLib.Utilities:**

```
    private static HttpClient fetcher = new HttpClient();

    public static async Task<JObject> GetPokemon(int n)
    {
        return await GetData(prefix + "pokemon/" + n + "/");
    }

    public static async Task<JObject> GetType(int n)
    {
        return await GetData(prefix + "type/" + n + "/");
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, JObject> resourceCache = new Dictionary<string, JObject>(); // TODO: Stale check

    public static async Task<JObject> GetData(string resourcePath, bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        if (!resourceCache.ContainsKey(resourcePath) || forceRefresh)
            resourceCache[resourcePath] = await FetchDataFromServer(resourcePath);

        return resourceCache[resourcePath];
    }

    public static async Task<JObject> FetchDataFromServer(string resourcePath)
    {
        try
        {
            string json = await fetcher.GetStringAsync(baseUri + resourcePath); // ***** this is the line that dies *****
            return JObject.Parse(json);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My code freezes at the labeled line under certain conditions, but I can't figure out what the issue is.  Note: typically, only GetPokemon() and GetItem() are called, but everything's public in the code for my debugging purposes.

Works:

- any calls to GetPokemon(), from the app's code-behind or from elsewhere within the library
- calls to GetType(), but only from the app's code-behind (GetDataButton_Click)

Not working:

- Calls to GetType() from elsewhere within the library, even though the path is virtually identical to that of GetPokemon()

The catch block for the GetStringAsync call is *never* triggered, and I've confirmed through the debugger that the URI I'm passing it is correct.  The full library code is on [my Github](https://github.com/Benjin/PokeLib).  It's also worth noting that *all* of these work correctly from the Test project within the library's same solution.

**Calling code:**

**Type.cs:**

```
    public Type(int id, bool constructNow = false)
    {
        this.id = id;

        try
        {
            if (constructNow) // this is being called with true
                Create().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public override async Task Create()
    {
        JObject data = await Utilities.GetType(id);

        if (data == null)
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Type ID #" + id + " does not exist");

        name = (string)data["name"];
        id = (int)data["id"];
        resourcePath = (string)data["resource_uri"];
    }
```

The calling Type.cs code is virtually identical to that of Pokemon.cs (including the .Wait()), so I don't think that would be the issue.

Any help/ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: No information about `fetcher` at all, no `GetItem()` method in the code example? Even though these are apparently the most important elements of your question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Whoops; `GetItem()` should've been `GetType()`, and `fetcher` is an HttpClient (as implied by the title, but I should've mentioned that explicitly.  Fixed.

Comment: Are you calling `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait` in any of your top level methods?

Comment: How about posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not that familiar with `WinRT`, but this looks like a classic deadlock due to the flow of the `WinRTSynchronizationContext` in each of your calls.

To avoid this completely, you can use the `InitializeAsync` pattern, as constructors cannot be asynchronous.

The pattern is simply, after constructing the object, make the caller invoke the `InitializeAsync` method:

```
public Type(int id, bool constructNow = false)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.constructNow = constructNow;
}

public Task InitializeAsync()
{
     return constructNow ? Create() : Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

And then call it:

```
var type = new Type(1, true);
await type.InitializeAsync();
```

While implementing code for an external library, it recommended to call async methods in the `async-await` pattern using [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). What it does is explicitly suppress the flow of the synchronization context to avoid potential mistakes where users call async methods with `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait`:

```
string json = await fetcher.GetStringAsync(baseUri + resourcePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Use this throughout you call chain.

Comment: I was using .Wait() (likely incorrectly) as a way to break from the await-async that perpetually bubbles upward.  Should I not be trying to leave asynchronous-ness as soon as possible and just embrace it all the way up to the UI's code-behind?

Comment: Exactly. Asynchronousy needs to bubble up all the way down, starting from the UI event handler. Dont supress it, embrace it.

Comment: Cool!  That seems to mostly be doing the trick, but now there's something else that's having difficulty, but I think that'll fit more in a separate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208172/loosely-ordered-concurrency-with-loops