# Loosely-ordered concurrency with loops?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, windows-runtime, async-await

I have the following code that is meant to fetch data from a REST service (the `Get(i)` calls), then populate a matrix (not shown; this happens within `addLabels()`) with their relationships.

All of the `Get()` calls can run in parallel to each other, but they must all be finished before anything enters the second loop (where, once again, the calls can run in parallel to each other).  The `addLabel()` calls depend on the work from the `Get()` calls to be complete.

** To anyone stumbling across this post, this code is the solution:**

```
private async void GetTypeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await PokeType.InitTypes(); // initializes relationships in the matrix

    var table = PokeType.EffectivenessMatrix;

    // pretty-printing the table
    // ...
    // ...
}

private static bool initialized = false;

public static async Task InitTypes()
{
    if (initialized) return;

    // await blocks until first batch is finished
    await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(1, NUM_TYPES /* inclusive */).Select(i => Get(i)));

    // doesn't need to be parallelized because it's quick work.
    foreach(PokeType type in cachedTypes.Values)
    {
        JObject data = type.GetJsonFromCache();
        addLabels(type, (JArray)data["super_effective"], Effectiveness.SuperEffectiveAgainst);
        addLabels(type, (JArray)data["ineffective"], Effectiveness.NotVeryEffectiveAgainst);
        addLabels(type, (JArray)data["no_effect"], Effectiveness.UselessAgainst);
    }

    initialized = true;
}

public static async Task<PokeType> Get(int id);
```

As the code is currently written, the `InitTypes()` method attempts to enter both loops simultaneously; the `cachedTypes` dictionary is empty because the first loop hasn't finished populating it yet, so it never runs and no relationships are constructed.

How can I properly structure this function?  Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't update your question with the answer, but rather post the question and create an **Edit** title to indicate what was the solution, so others can see what the problem was and how it was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel and `async-await` don't go together well. Your async lambda expression is actually `async void` since `Parallel.For` excpects an `Action<int>`, which means that `Parallel.For` can't wait for that operation to complete.

If you're trying to call `Get(i)` multiple times concurrently and wait for them to complete before moving on you need to use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(1, NUM_TYPES).Select(() => Get(i)))
```

Comment: Also, it is debatable whether the `Parallel.ForEach()` loop should be parallel in the first place. `addLabels()` may or may not be thread-safe, but even if it is, are the computations there really slow enough to justify the overhead of using `Parallel` instead of just a plain `foreach` statement?

Comment: @i3arnon Forgive someone who hasn't worked with this before; I see how this works in lieu of the standard for-loop, but how can I (cleanly) use it to replace the for-each?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Didn't realize Parallel.ForEach had much overhead.  They're just doing JSON parsing, so I can probably do those synchronously.  A standard foreach will be fine because the previous loop is awaited, right?

Comment: @Benjin yes. And since it's synchronous, if you've wanted to parallelize it you can use `Parallel` or `Task.Run` (as long as you're making sure it's thread-safe).